# RouteConfigproblem in mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my RegisterRoutes  method i like to set companyName with value like

" http://localhost:22146/abccompany/subject/Index ", I have done with this following code.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "{company}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { company = "abccompany", controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

           );
```

Its working, But when my subject controller hit without "/index" then does not hit that action.

like " http://localhost:22146/abccompany/subject" then not working.

Please show me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Because you set the default action to be `Login` when you registered the route. Change it to `index` action and it will work.

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "{company}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { company = "abccompany", controller = "Account",
                                             action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

           );
```

Comment: But how to set login as startup view.

Comment: You can't have both. If you do that, Index wont be default action.